# PHP Firestore cannot handle unknown field collection_Id on message google.firestore.v1.StructuredQuery.CollectionSelector

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a project and using firestore with PHP. I created a Firestore class according to documentation below.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/4149481c23eeb314144ae15c74fa47c5eaf8f3a6/firestore/src

Project is working in localhost with xamp. But it's not working on the server. I didn't understand why it's not working :s Can you help me ?

Thank you.

Getting an error in the **getWhere()** function on this line :

```
 $documents = $query->documents();
```

**Function getWhere() in `Firestore.php :`**

```
  /**
     * Get document(s) with where condition
     * @param string $collectionName
     * @param string $field
     * @param string $operator
     * @param $value
     * @return array
     */
    public function getWhere(string $nerden, string $collectionName, array $whereQuery, string $orderBy = "", string $orderBySort = "desc", int $limit = 0)
    
    {
        // echo $nerden . "<br>";
        // echo $limit . "<br>";
        // echo $orderBySort . "<br>";
        // echo $orderBy . "<br>";
        // echo "<pre>";
        // print_r($whereQuery);
        // echo "</pre>";

        $arr = [];
        $collectionRef = $this->db->collection($collectionName);

        $query = null;

        foreach ($whereQuery as  $param) {
            # code...
            if ($query == null) {
                $query = $collectionRef->where($param["field"], $param["operator"], $param["value"]);
            } else {
                $query = $query->where($param["field"], $param["operator"], $param["value"]);
            }
        }

        if ($query != null) {

            if ($orderBy != "") {
                $query = $query->orderBy($orderBy, $orderBySort);
            }
            if ($limit > 0) {
                $query = $query->limit($limit);
            }

            $documents = $query->documents();

            $x = 0;
            foreach ($documents as $document) {
                if ($document->exists()) {
                    // printf('Document id  for document %s:' . PHP_EOL, $document->id());
                    // print_r($document->data());
                    // printf(PHP_EOL);
                    $arr[$x]["data"] = $document->data();
                    $arr[$x]["id"] = $document->id();
                    $x++;
                } else {
                    // printf('Document %s does not exist!' . PHP_EOL, $document->id());
                }
            }

            return $arr;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**Line 120** in *`yorumlari_listele.php`*

```
$egitici_aktiviteler = yorumlariGetir(1);
```

**`Function yorumlariGetir()`**

```
// durum parametresine bağlı olarak yorumları getirir
// durum : 0 -> Onay bekleyen yorumları getirir
// durum : 1 -> Onaylanan yorumları getirir
function yorumlariGetir($durum)
{
  global $db_firebase;

  // Onay bekleyen yorumları getir
  $whereQuery = array(
    array(
      "field" => "durum",
      "operator" => "=",
      "value" => $durum,
    ),
  );

  $sonuc = $db_firebase->getWhere("yorumlariGetir", "reviews", $whereQuery, "tarih", "asc");

  return  $sonuc;
}
```

***This is FirebaseDb Class:***

```
/*
Yazar : Mustafa SOLAK
Tarih : 14.09.2022 00:02
*/

//require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FieldValue;
use Google\Cloud\Core\Timestamp;
use DateTime;

class FirebaseDB
{
    private $db;
    private $projectId = "*********";
    private static $instance = null;

    private function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new FirestoreClient([
            'projectId' => $this->projectId,
        ]);
        // print("Created Cloud Firestore client with project ID: $this->projectId <br>");
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new FirebaseDB();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function getConnection()
    {
        return $this->db;
    }

    /**
     * Create new document with data
     * @param string $collectionName
     * @param string $docName
     * @param array $data
     * @return bool|string
     */
    public function newDocument(string $collectionName, string $docName, array $data = [])
    {
        try {
            // set var olanı günceller. yoksa oluşturur.
            $this->db->collection($collectionName)->document($docName)->set($data, ["merge" => true]);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            return $exception->getMessage();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get document and all data with checking for exists
     * @param string $collectionName
     * @param string $docName
     * @return array|null|string
     */
    public function getDocument(string $collectionName, string $docName)
    {
        try {
            if (empty($collectionName)) throw new Exception('Collection name missing');
            else if (empty($docName)) throw new Exception('Document name missing');
            if ($this->db->collection($collectionName)->document($docName)->snapshot()->exists()) {
                return $this->db->collection($collectionName)->document($docName)->snapshot()->data();
            } else {
                throw new Exception('Document are not exists');
            }
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            return $exception->getMessage();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get document(s) with where condition
     * @param string $collectionName
     * @param string $field
     * @param string $operator
     * @param $value
     * @return array
     */
    public function getWhere(string $nerden, string $collectionName, array $whereQuery, string $orderBy = "", string $orderBySort = "desc", int $limit = 0)
    // public function getWhere(string $collectionName, string $field, string $operator,  $value)
    {
        // echo $nerden . "<br>";
        // echo $limit . "<br>";
        // echo $orderBySort . "<br>";
        // echo $orderBy . "<br>";
        // echo "<pre>";
        // print_r($whereQuery);
        // echo "</pre>";

        $arr = [];
        $collectionRef = $this->db->collection($collectionName);

        $query = null;

        foreach ($whereQuery as  $param) {
            # code...
            if ($query == null) {
                $query = $collectionRef->where($param["field"], $param["operator"], $param["value"]);
            } else {
                $query = $query->where($param["field"], $param["operator"], $param["value"]);
            }
        }

        if ($query != null) {

            if ($orderBy != "") {
                $query = $query->orderBy($orderBy, $orderBySort);
            }
            if ($limit > 0) {
                $query = $query->limit($limit);
            }

            $documents = $query->documents();

            $x = 0;
            foreach ($documents as $document) {
                if ($document->exists()) {
                    // printf('Document id  for document %s:' . PHP_EOL, $document->id());
                    // print_r($document->data());
                    // printf(PHP_EOL);
                    $arr[$x]["data"] = $document->data();
                    $arr[$x]["id"] = $document->id();
                    $x++;
                } else {
                    // printf('Document %s does not exist!' . PHP_EOL, $document->id());
                }
            }

            return $arr;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get documents under the specific collection
     * @param string $collectionName
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCollection(string $collectionName, $orderBy = "", $orderBySort = "")
    {
        $arr = [];
        $collectionRef = $this->db->collection($collectionName);

        if ($orderBy != "") {
            $query = $collectionRef->orderBy($orderBy, $orderBySort);
            $documents = $query->documents();
        }else{
            $documents = $collectionRef->documents();
        }
        $x = 0;
        foreach ($documents as $document) {
            if ($document->exists()) {
                // printf('Document id  for document %s:' . PHP_EOL, $document->id());
                // print_r($document->data());
                // printf(PHP_EOL);
                $arr[$x]["data"] = $document->data();
                $arr[$x]["id"] = $document->id();
                $x++;
            } else {
                // printf('Document %s does not exist!' . PHP_EOL, $document->id());
            }
        }

        return $arr;
    }


    public function arrayContains()
    {
        $citiesRef = $this->db->collection('icerikler');
        # [START fs_array_membership]
        # [START firestore_query_filter_array_contains]
        $containsQuery = $citiesRef->where('konu', 'array-contains', '3');
        # [END firestore_query_filter_array_contains]
        # [END fs_array_membership]
        foreach ($containsQuery->documents() as $document) {
            printf('Document %s returned by query regions array-contains west_coast' . PHP_EOL, $document->id());
        }
    }


    /**
     * Create new collection
     * @param string $collectionName
     * @param string $docName
     * @param array $data
     * @return bool|string
     */
    public function newCollection(string $collectionName, string $docName, array $data = [])
    {
        try {
            $this->db->collection($collectionName)->document($docName)->create($data);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            return $exception->getMessage();
        }
    }

    /**
     * checks whether collection is exists or not
     * @param string $collectionName
     * @return bool|string
     */
    public function isCollectionExists(string $collectionName)
    {
        try {
            $documents = $this->db->collection($collectionName)->limit(1)->documents();
            // it means collection exists
            if (!$documents->isEmpty())
                return 1;

            // oops! collection does not exists
            else
                return -1;
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            return $exception->getMessage();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Drop exists document in collection
     * @param string $collectionName
     * @param string $docName
     * @return void
     */
    public function dropDocument(string $collectionName, string $docName)
    {
        try {
            $this->db->collection($collectionName)->document($docName)->delete();
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            return $exception->getMessage();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update a document with increment operation
     * Increases Field value if you use positive number 
     * Decreases Field value  if you use negative number
     * By the way you can use this function both operations
     * @param string $collectionName
     * @param string $docName
     * @param string $field -> to be updated
     * @param string $amount -> increment amount
     * @return void
     */
    public function fieldIncrementOrDecrement(string $collectionName, string $docName, $field, $amount)
    {
        $cityRef = $this->db->collection($collectionName)->document($docName);

        try {
            $cityRef->update([
                ['path' => $field, 'value' => FieldValue::increment($amount)]
            ]);
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            return $exception->getMessage();
        }
    }


    public function updateField(string $collectionName, string $docName, $field, $value)
    {
        try {
            $cityRef = $this->db->collection($collectionName)->document($docName);
            $cityRef->update([
                ['path' => $field, 'value' => $value]
            ]);
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            return $exception->getMessage();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Set review count data
     * @param string $collectionName
     * @param string $docName
     * @param array $data
     * @return bool|string
     */
    public function setReviewCounts($collectionName, $docName, $data, $field, $value)
    {
        try {

            $data[$field] = FieldValue::increment($value);

            // set var olanı günceller. yoksa oluşturur.
            $this->db->collection($collectionName)->document($data["id"] . "_" . $data["type"])->set($data, ["merge" => true]);

            return true;
        } catch (Exception $exception) {

            return $exception->getMessage();
        }
    }
    
}
```

**Error Text :**

`Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: cannot handle unknown field collection_Id on message google.firestore.v1.StructuredQuery.CollectionSelector in /home/evok9367/public_html/mustafasolakweb/vendor/google/gax/src/Serializer.php:391 Stack trace: #0 /home/evok9367/public_html/mustafasolakweb/vendor/google/gax/src/Serializer.php(369): Google\ApiCore\Serializer->decodeMessageImpl() #1 /home/evok9367/public_html/mustafasolakweb/vendor/google/gax/src/Serializer.php(413): Google\ApiCore\Serializer->decodeElement() #2 /home/evok9367/public_html/mustafasolakweb/vendor/google/gax/src/Serializer.php(127): Google\ApiCore\Serializer->decodeMessageImpl() #3 /home/evok9367/public_html/mustafasolakweb/vendor/google/cloud/Firestore/src/Connection/Grpc.php(215): Google\ApiCore\Serializer->decodeMessage() #4 /home/evok9367/public_html/mustafasolakweb/vendor/google/cloud/Firestore/src/Query.php(204): Google\Cloud\Firestore\Connection\Grpc->runQuery() #5 [internal function]: Google\Cloud\Firestore\Query->Google\Cloud\Firestore{closure}() #6 /home/evok9367/public_html/mustafasolakweb/vendor/google/cloud/Core/src/ExponentialBackoff.php(80): call_user_func_array() #7 /home/evok9367/public_html/mustafasolakweb/vendor/google/cloud/Firestore/src/Query.php(244): Google\Cloud\Core\ExponentialBackoff->execute() #8 /home/evok9367/public_html/mustafasolakweb/Firestore.php(127): Google\Cloud\Firestore\Query->documents() #9 /home/evok9367/public_html/mustafasolakweb/screens/yorumlar/yorumlar_listele.php(329): FirebaseDB->getWhere() #10 /home/evok9367/public_html/mustafasolakweb/screens/yorumlar/yorumlar_listele.php(120): yorumlariGetir() #11 /home/evok9367/public_html/mustafasolakweb/index.php(33): include('/home/evok9367/...') #12 {main} Next Google\ApiCore\ValidationException: Error decoding message: cannot handle unknown field collection_Id on message google.firestore.v1.StructuredQuery.CollectionSelector in /home/evok9367/public_html/mustafasolakweb/vendor/google/gax/src/Serializer.php:129 Stack trace: #0 /home/evok9367/public_html/mustafasolakweb/vendor/google/cloud/Firestore/src/Connection/Grpc.php(215): Google\ApiCore\Serializer->decodeMessage() #1 /home/evok9367/public_html/mustafasolakweb/vendor/google/cloud/Firestore/src/Query.php(204): Google\Cloud\Firestore\Connection\Grpc->runQuery() #2 [internal function]: Google\Cloud\Firestore\Query->Google\Cloud\Firestore{closure}() #3 /home/evok9367/public_html/mustafasolakweb/vendor/google/cloud/Core/src/ExponentialBackoff.php(80): call_user_func_array() #4 /home/evok9367/public_html/mustafasolakweb/vendor/google/cloud/Firestore/src/Query.php(244): Google\Cloud\Core\ExponentialBackoff->execute() #5 /home/evok9367/public_html/mustafasolakweb/Firestore.php(127): Google\Cloud\Firestore\Query->documents() #6 /home/evok9367/public_html/mustafasolakweb/screens/yorumlar/yorumlar_listele.php(329): FirebaseDB->getWhere() #7 /home/evok9367/public_html/mustafasolakweb/screens/yorumlar/yorumlar_listele.php(120): yorumlariGetir() #8 /home/evok9367/public_html/mustafasolakweb/index.php(33): include('/home/evok9367/...') #9 {main} thrown in /home/evok9367/public_html/mustafasolakweb/vendor/google/gax/src/Serializer.php on line 129`

**There are some Turkish words in the code and I added English translations, hope it helps.**

nerden = fromWhere

yorumlari_listele *=* list_comments

egitici_aktiviteler = activities

yorumlariGetir = getComments

durum = state

sonuc = result

tarih = date

I tried all the things, changed the code like
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/4149481c23eeb314144ae15c74fa47c5eaf8f3a6/firestore/src

Comment: I stuck on this part. Still can't solve the problem... Anyone else to help?

Comment: I solved the problem.
I was using this function in ayarlar.php file which is I included in at the top of the  index.php file. I commented and uncommented all code line by line until it works.  Look what ı have found. 
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'tr_TR.UTF-8'); 

I dont know why !But now it works...